# How can i show/create the inline box of vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Im making an extension and want to use the inline box in my code action how can i create/show the input box?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the only way to get that box is to call the [vscode rename command](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/master/extensions/typescript-language-features/src/features/refactor.ts#L75), and i think you also need a `RenameProvider` for it to work properly.

Answer (score 0):

This is renaming : Press the key F2

Comment: i rephrased my question, thanks for answering, this is not what im looking for.